# React Website shows stock React icon when sending via text message

Tags: reactjs

I have a react website I have developed deployed on AWS. I have changed the favicon within the React app and the proper icon shows when viewing it within a browser (mobile or desktop) but when I attempt to send a link to my website via text message it shows the stock react icon. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Did you change `og:image`?

Comment: Go [to this web site](https://www.favicon-generator.org) generate your favicon and look at all links created. You can download and use that icon file if you want all the various sizes.

Comment: @Konrad I don't seem to have anything in my React project with og:image

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I had only updated `<link rel=manifest` in index.html to point to my manifest file and favicons. I needed to also update `<link rel=apple-touch-icon`.